# VSCode REST Client : use the result of a request in another request

Tags: rest, visual-studio-code, jwt, vscode-extensions, vscode-restclient

Using VSCode Rest Client, I would like to do a post request that returns a jwt token and use it in another GET request

For the moment I am doing this POST request in a file `auth.http`:

```
# Login
# @name tokenAPI
POST {{baseUrl}}/login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "Username": "myuser",
    "Password": "mypassword"
}
```

I get this answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 16 Dec 2023 14:16:45 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
  "token": "theheader.thepayload.thesignature"
}
```

I have this settings with a authToken where I have to enter manually the value for authToken each time it changes, in the correct environment.

In the file `.vscode/settings.json`, I have:

```
{
    "rest-client.environmentVariables": {
        "local": {
            "baseUrl": "http://localhost",
            "authToken": "theheader.thepayload.thesignature"
        },
        "docker": {
            "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
            "authToken": "",
        },
        "prod": {
            "baseUrl": "http://produrl.net",
            "authToken": "",
        }
    }
}
```

I have another request in `user.http`:

```
GET {{baseUrl}}/User
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
```

I would like to store the response of the POST authentication request and reuse it in other requests, it would be something like this:

```
# Login
# @name tokenAPI
POST {{baseUrl}}/login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "Username": "myuser",
    "Password": "mypassword"
}


@authToken = {{tokenAPI.response.body.token}}
```

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you stay in the same file, a solution is

In a request file named for example user.http

```
    @baseUrl = "http://localhost"
    # Login
    # @name tokenAPI
    POST {{baseUrl}}/Auth/login HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json
    
    {
        "Username": "myuser",
        "Password": "mypassword"
    }
    ###
    
    @authToken = {{tokenAPI.response.body.token}}
    # Get User
    # @name getUser
    GET {{baseUrl}}/User
    Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
```